# If, else & while bug (not activating / activating twice)

Tags: c, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I'm having this problem in where when the player choose to attack. It won't print anything at first but will only print when the player hits the knight. Something else is also if the player chooses an invalid choice in gender, the first mistake will print once but if the mistake happen again it will print twice. I would appreciate any help, just doing my lil' project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char enter = 0;
    char pNAME[30];
    char pGENDER;
    char pWEAPON[20];
    char pARMOR [10];
    int  pWEAPONID;
    int choice1,choice2 = 0,choice3;
    int pAGE;
    int pATK = 0;
    int pHP = 30;
    int pATKS = 10;
    int pATKC = 0;
    int knightHP = 25;
    int knightATKS = 20;
    int knightATKC;
    int kingHP = 30;
    int kingATKC;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));


    printf("While you are enjoying your breakfast at your house, suddenly you get teleported to a different dimension and no one to be seen except an old man.\n");

    printf("\nOld Man: What is your name warrior?\n");
    printf("\nInsert name:");
    scanf("%s",pNAME);
    fpurge( stdin );

    printf("\nInsert gender (m/f):");
    scanf("%c",&pGENDER);
    fpurge( stdin );
    while ( pGENDER != 'f' &&pGENDER != 'm' )
    {
        printf("\nInvalid entry, please try again.\n");
        printf("\nInsert gender (m/f):");
        scanf("%c",&pGENDER);
    }

    printf("\nOld Man: Now how old are you warrior?\n");
    printf("\nInsert Age:");
    scanf("%d",&pAGE);
    fpurge( stdin );
    if ( pAGE < 18)
    {
        printf("\nOy mate! No stalker!\n");
        printf("\nTeleporting back to reality...\n");

        return 0;
    }

    if ( pAGE > 80)
    {
        printf("\nNo oldies allowed!\n");
        printf("\nTeleporting back to reality...\n");

        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nOld Man: Welcome warrior I fear the knights has taken over our kingdom, and you, %s, are the only one who can save us.\n",pNAME);
    printf("\n%s: How am I suppose to do that?[Enter]\n",pNAME);
    while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }


    printf("Old Man: Pick one of these three items\n");
    printf("\n[1] Axe : Damage = 7\t   Accuracy = 70%%  Critical = 7%%\n");   //
    printf("\n[2] Sword : Damage = 5\t Accuracy = 77%%  Critical = 8%%\n");
    printf("\n[3] Knife : Damage = 3\t Accuracy = 83%%  Critical = 9%%\n");
    printf("\nYou choose: ");
    scanf("%d",&pWEAPONID);

    if (pWEAPONID == 1)
    {
        pATK = 8;
        pATKS = 14;     // 10/14 chance
        strcpy(pWEAPON, "Axe");
    }
    if (pWEAPONID == 2)
    {
        pATK = 6;
        pATKS = 14;     // 10/13 chance
        strcpy(pWEAPON, "Sword");
    }
    if (pWEAPONID == 3)
    {
        pATK = 4;
        pATKS = 12;     // 10/12 chance
        strcpy(pWEAPON, "Knife");
    }
    if (pWEAPONID > 3)
    {
        printf("\nYou are gonna be fighting with your bare fist");
        pATK = 2;
        pATKS = 11;      // 10/11 chance
        strcpy(pWEAPON, "Fist");
    }

    printf("\nOld Man: Good choice, you chose the %s, now continue foward to destroy The Evil King\n",pWEAPON);
    printf("\nWhile you are continuing your journey to destroy The Evil King, you come face to face with a knight\n");
    printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
    printf("\n[1] Run [2] Battle:");
    scanf("%d",&choice1);

    if (choice1 == 1) //Dead
    {
        printf("\nYou attempted to run, but the knight chases you with his horse and a spear.\n");
        printf("\nThe knight stabs you right through your body.\n");
        printf("\nYou are dead, thanks for playing.\n");
        return 0;
    }


    while (pHP != 0 && knightHP != 0) // Combat starts
    {   
        knightATKC = rand()%knightATKS;     // 15/20 chance
        sleep(1);
        // Knight's turn
        if ( knightATKC == 1 || knightATKC == 2 || knightATKC == 3 || knightATKC == 4 || knightATKC == 5 || knightATKC == 6 || knightATKC == 7 || knightATKC == 8 || knightATKC == 9 || knightATKC == 10 || knightATKC == 11 || knightATKC == 0 )
        {
            printf("\nThe knight swings his spear at %s\n",pNAME);
            printf("The knight hits %s for 4 HP\n",pNAME);
            pHP = pHP - 4;
            printf("%s has %d/30 HP\n",pNAME,pHP);
            if (pHP == 0 || pHP <0)
            {
                printf("\nYou fell to the ground heavily damages, while the knight lungs at your for the final hit\n");
                printf("\nYou are dead, thanks for playing.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
            printf("[1] Attack [2] Charge your attack [3] Heal:"); // Charge and Heal not activated yet
            scanf("%d",&choice1);

        }
        else if (knightATKC == 12 || knightATKC == 13 )
        {
            printf("\nThe knight slashes his spear at %s\n",pNAME);
            printf("The knight critically hit %s for 6 HP\n",pNAME);
            pHP = pHP - 6;
            printf("%s has %d/30 HP\n",pNAME,pHP);
            if (pHP == 0 || pHP <0)
            {
                printf("\nYou fell to the ground heavily damages, while the knight lungs at your for the final hit\n");
                printf("\nYou are dead, thanks for playing.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
            printf("[1] Attack [2] Charge your attack [3] Heal:"); // Charge and Heal not activated yet
            scanf("%d",&choice2);
        }
        else if (knightATKC == 14)
        {
            printf("\nThe knight's horse kicks %s\n",pNAME);
            printf("The knight's horse hit %s for 8 HP\n",pNAME);
            pHP = pHP - 8;
            printf("%s has %d/30 HP\n",pNAME,pHP);
            if (pHP == 0 || pHP <0)
            {
                printf("\nYou fell to the ground heavily damages, while the knight lungs at your for the final hit\n");
                printf("\nYou are dead, thanks for playing.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
            printf("[1] Attack [2] Charge your attack [3] Heal:");
            scanf("%d",&choice2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThe knight swings his spear at %s\n",pNAME);
            printf("You blocked his spear with your %s\n",pWEAPON);
            printf("%s has %d/30 HP\n",pNAME,pHP);
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
            printf("[1] Attack [2] Charge your attack [3] Heal:"); // Charge and Heal not activated yet
            scanf("%d",&choice2);
        }

        // Player's turns
        if (choice2 == 1)
        {
            pATKC = rand()%pATKS;
            if (pATKC == 0 || pATKC == 1 || pATKC == 2 || pATKC == 3 || pATKC == 4 || pATKC == 5 || pATKC == 6 || pATKC == 7 || pATKC == 8 || pATKC == 9)
            {
                printf("\nYou swing your %s at the knight\n",pWEAPON);
                printf("You hit the knight with your %d\n",pATK);
                knightHP = knightHP - pATK;
                printf("The knight has %d/25\n",knightHP);
                if (knightHP == 0 || knightHP <0)
                {
                    printf("\nYou fell to the ground heavily damages, while the knight lungs at your for the final hit\n");
                    printf("\nYou are dead, thanks for playing.\n");
                }
                printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
                printf("[1] Run [2] Attempt to block\n");
                scanf("%d",&choice3);
            }
            else if (pATKC == 10)
            {
                printf("\nYou swing your %s at the knight\n",pWEAPON);
                printf("You critically hit the knight for %f\n",pATK * 1.5);
                knightHP = knightHP - (pATK * 1.5);
                printf("The knight has %d/25\n",knightHP);
                printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
                printf("[1] Run [2] Attempt to block\n");
                scanf("%d",&choice3);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nYou swing your %s at the knight\n",pWEAPON);
                printf("The knight intercept your %s with his spear\n",pWEAPON);
                printf("The knight has %d/25\n",knightHP);
                printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
                printf("[1] Run [2] Attempt to block\n"); // Not activated yet
                scanf("%d",&choice3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: Debugging: breakpoints, single stepping, examining variable values. Same as the other essentially same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343335/while-command-activating-twice-c-language) on the essentially same code.

Comment: It wil lmake debugging and understanding of the code easier if it is refactored (broken-up) into several functions, each function handling a small portion of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does not compile, so it certainly does not run.

here are a few of the many listed problems with the code

Always enable all warnings when compiling.

For gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

```
line:column: message

35:5:  warning implicit declaration of function `fpurge`
224:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
27:9:  warning: unused variable `kingATKC`
26:9:  warning: unused variable `kingHP`
15:10: warning: unused variable `pARMOR`
```

BTW: `fpurge` is not a supported function in the stdio.h header file

Suggest, rather than calling `fpurge()`, use:

```
while( '\n' != getchar() );
```

when calling scanf(), always check the returned value, not the parameter value, to assure the operation was successful

when inputting the 'gender', apply `tolower` to the value so user could enter either upper or lower case

this code: around line 232 is killing the hero when it should be killing the knight

```
            if (knightHP == 0 || knightHP <0)
            {
                printf("\nYou fell to the ground heavily damages, while the knight lungs at your for the final hit\n");
                printf("\nYou are dead, thanks for playing.\n");
            }
```

upon any death, the resulting HP can be less than 0 however this line:

```
while (pHP != 0 && knightHP != 0) // Combat starts
```

only terminates the loop if HP == 0  it should be:

```
while (pHP > 0 && knightHP > 0) // Combat starts
```

Suggest, for a combat sequence, that there is only one place where the hero can input a decision about what they want to do next.

Suggest, make each combat activity a separate sub function.

The above two suggestions will greatly increase the simplicity of each function and make the code much easier to debug.